# TweenAnimationBuilder animation is too fast

Tags: flutter

Animation in Flutter is playing too fast.
With **Duration** of 5 seconds it ends instantly, with Duration of 5 minutes it ends in about 10 seconds.

```
class _TimeLeftIndicatorState extends State<TimeLeftIndicator> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double getRadiansFromTotalTime(currentTime) {
    return 1.00 - (currentTime * 100 / this.widget.timeInitial) * 0.01;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        width: 250,
        child: TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          builder: (_, double value, __) => 
               RepaintBoundary(
                     child: CustomPaint(
                               painter: TimePiePainter(value)
                            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TimePiePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;
  TimePiePainter(this.value);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint _paint = Paint()
      ..color = Color.lerp(Colors.green, Colors.redAccent, value > 0.6 ? value * 1.5 : value)!
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
      -pi / 2,
      pi * 2 - pi * 2 * value,
      true,
      _paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant TimePiePainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have found the solution for this unintuitive resolution and post it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that some devices have problem with this. Like my Huawei Y6 (2018)
Another person on github also had this issue, but I wanted to add this solution here, as it will be easier to find, because it was the only place I found it after long time. So it will save somebody a lot of time.
Solution is:

> I went in the developer options and switched the "Windows animation
> scale" and "Transition animation scale" from "Animation off" to
> "Animation scale 1x" then put them back to "Animation off".

Did exactly same steps and it worked on my device too.

Link to the answer: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60917